# Selenium Webdriver works fast when network/internet is turned off

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a very peculiar issue with Selenium Webdriver. All of sudden my selenium scripts written in python have started to execute very slow in both firefox and chrome.

The script execution returns to its normal speed when I manually turn off the network/internet through my laptop's wifi button after a webpage is loaded. The same scripts run at normal speed on another computer (on my office network) where I connect to internet through VPN.

Another example is when I run my scripts on a locally stored webpage file (htm). The scripts run superfast when internet is turned off but run equally slow when the internet is turned on.

I do not use a proxy server.

Comment: It feels like webdriver is routing the HTTP requests through internet.

Comment: I guess you are testing the page after the onload event is fired. And if you have no internet to load external libraries it will load faster

Comment: I am simply traversing the DOM elements and print their 'text' values on terminal. It takes less than a second to complete this task when internet is turned off. The same task takes around 50 seconds with internet turned on.

Comment: Do you have external scrips images CSS?

Comment: How about the version of the `selenium` package - which one are you using? Does upgrading/downgrading change the performance aspect?

Comment: The same scripts were running perfectly fine few days ago on the same version of selenium. The only thing that changed since then was the renewal of my Internet plan. (Can a setting change by my ISP affect it?) My selenium version is 2.52.0

Comment: Added more info to my question.